# Java - LWJGL display screen resolution with JComboBox

Tags: java, exception, awt, lwjgl, resolution

EDIT FOUND THE ANSWER:
The x's in my resolution, it was some kind of other x.
So when I tried to split, it didn't reconize the entry, which was the normal x.

I'm making a game with lwjgl, and I made a menu in which you choose the size and FPS of the game.
The weird problem is that when I choose a higher resolution for example 1600 x 900, the program doesn't run and I get this exception.
http://pastebin.com/kc27gMTa

But when I choose a lower resolution (640 x 360), the game runs just fine.
The menu is JComboBox, and this is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnO9N.jpg

I format the code with

```
String[] resolutionSplit = resolutionChooser.getSelectedItem().toString().split(" x ");
int width = Integer.parseInt(resolutionSplit[0]);
int height = Integer.parseInt(resolutionSplit[1]);
Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
```

Comment: What's the code for StartGUI.mouseReleased ?

Comment: That's the mouselistener, that executes when the start button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

The x's in my resolution, it was some kind of other x.
So when I tried to split, it didn't reconize the entry, which was the normal x.